# Select dropdown values in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, office-interop, excel-interop

I am trying to automate an Excel app using C#. I managed to trigger the macros using Microsoft Office Interops but I am unable to select a dropdown value from the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Excel Interop does provide an interface for drop down object. Please see refer to this link, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.dropdown_members.aspx

The sample code below should also give you some ideas on how to get reference and use the drop down in the code

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
string str = @"C:\myExcelFile.xlsx";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename: str);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet1 = workbook.ActiveSheet;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = worksheet1.get_Range("A1","A1");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDowns xlDropDowns;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDown xlDropDown;
xlDropDowns = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDowns)(workbook.ActiveSheet.DropDowns(Type.Missing)));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. I get xlDropDowns count as 0. For now I just managed to set the cell value to the specific dropdown option which works fine.